# How to rename existing styles in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, django-ckeditor

In my webpage we'll only allow users to use `H3` and `H4`, but it's confusing to see these as "Title 3" and "Title 4". I wanted to rename these as "Title" and "Subtitle", but setting `format_h3.name` doesn't seem to affect that.

I can't write custom JS to configure the editor as I'm using a Django Plugin, that actually converts a python dictionary into the final JSON config used.

The relevant part of what I tried is as follows:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'allowedContent': 'h3 h4 p b i u a[*]',
        'format_p': {'name': 'Standard text', 'element': 'p'},
        'format_h3': {'name': 'Title', 'element': 'h3'},
        'format_h4': {'name': 'Subtitle', 'element': 'h4'},
        'toolbar': [
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Format']},
            {'name': 'basicstyles', 'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink']},
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no ability to change formats names in CKEditor via configuration. I've filled a [feature request](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1285) for that.

However if you are able to modify editor's files, you could always alter language entries directly, located in `plugins/format/lang/<language>.js`.

The second workaround is to modify `format` plugin source, especially [`init` function](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/a7d927946f4a16f38318a9aa8a94b59b52493fdb/plugins/format/plugin.js#L52-L61):

```
init: function() {
    this.startGroup( lang.panelTitle );

    for ( var tag in styles ) {
        var label = config[ 'format_' + tag ] && config[ 'format_' + tag ].name || lang[ 'tag_' + tag ];

        // Add the tag entry to the panel list.
        this.add( tag, styles[ tag ].buildPreview( label ), label );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sad developer is sad. But thanks, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

This still isn't solved officially in CKEditor 4, but I did figure this sledgehammer approach out...

```
CKEDITOR.lang.load('en', 'en', function(lc, data) {
    data.format.tag_p = 'Standard text';
    data.format.tag_h3 = 'Title';
    data.format.tag_h4 = 'Subtitle';
});
```

According to the manual, the first 'en' is the language code you wish to load, and the second is the fallback language. You need to override the tag in the callback, otherwise you will get errors about the tag not existing.

This sample will change the text for EVERY CKEditor instance on the page you run this. It will also change it for every plugin that uses those translations in said instances.

I haven't found a per instance way of doing this yet.

Comment: Got this working using en-gb instead of en. Thanks for the great hack!